# Firebase database.ref().once().forEach() behaviour when using async/await

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

I am a little confused by how iterating thru Firebase Realtime Database nodes works when using await. How can I perform queries inside loops?

My data is structured in three levels (notes --> userId --> noteId)

```
notes:{
  -ABC: {
    -123:{ ... },
    -456:{ ... }
  },
  -CDE:{
    -789:{ ... },
    -011:{ ... }
  }
}
```

My code using traditional .once() callback function - this works.

```
await database.ref('notes').once('value', (topSnap) => {
  console.log('topSnap', topSnap.key)
  topSnap.forEach((childSnap)=>{
    console.log('childSnap', childSnap.key)
    childSnap.forEach((notSnap)=>{
      console.log('notSnap', notSnap.key)
    })
  })
})
```

Output

```
topSnap notes
childSnap -ABC
notSnap -123
notSnap -456
childSnap -CDE
notSnap -789
notSnap -011
```

When using async/await I get another result!

```
await database.ref('notes').once('value', async (topSnap) => {
  console.log('topSnap', topSnap.key)
  topSnap.forEach(async (childSnap)=>{
    console.log('childSnap', childSnap.key)
    userSnap.forEach(async (notSnap)=>{
      console.log('notSnap', notSnap.key)
      const ref = notSnap.val().refStr
      const nestedSnap = await database.ref(ref).once('value')
    })
  })
})
```

Output

```
topSnap notes
childSnap -ABC
notSnap -123
```

In essence - When using `async / await` the `forEach()` loop does not loop all values - when omitting async/await the `forEach()` loop works as expected.

How can I perform queries inside loops? Kind regards /K

Comment: From what I understand, you take your values with `.once('value')` and then you just `forEach()` over them, right? I don't think you fetch new values with every forEach(). This means that you won't need the `async` inside. Also, be careful with it: `async` marks the function that it will return a promise as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You are not doing anything with your promise so it seems like it gets 'lost'

Comment: Hi @DavidBuzatu! Thank you! Actually - What I would like to do is fetch more data based on the "noteSnap". :)  Have updated the code example. /K

Comment: So, what is your question?  Are you asking for an explanation as to why the observed behavior is the way you see it?  Or are you asking how to perform more queries inside the loop?  On Stack Overflow, you can only really have one question per post, otherwise it becomes difficult or impossible to answer decisively.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for the reply! I have changed the question to only ask how to perform more queries inside the loop. Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using .map() with Promise.all allows me to iterate an Array while using async/await.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

await Promise.all(arr.map(async (i) => {
    await sleep(10 - i);
    console.log(i);
}));

// 3
// 2
// 1

console.log("Finished async");
// Finished async
```

More on the subject:
https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-foreach-in-javascript/